# Why is just the file name part up to first space output on processing a file names list with FOR?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, vmware-workstation

I am trying to get listed running virtual machines from VMware workstation with using command `vmrun list`.

```
for /F %%G in ('vmrun list') do echo %%~fG
```

The problem is that virtual machine images located in folder `VMWare Images` like

**"C:\VMWare Images\VMServer\My Test Server.vmx"**

are output as

**"C:\VMWare"**

How can I get full path?
Or is there only the solution to rename my folder and virtual machines so that their names do not include any space?

Comment: You haven't changed/disabled the default `for /f` delimiter space/tab, so insert `for /F "delims=" %%G in ('vmrun list') do echo %%~fG`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `"tokens=*"` to get whole lines, not a substring until first space:

```
 for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('vmrun list') do echo %%~fG
```

Comment: Nitpicking: To get the ***whole*** line disable `"delims="`. The outcome is nearly identical, `"tokens=*"` will also strip leading spaces (what might be desired sometimes)+1.

Comment: `"tokens=*"` results in running line splitting with default delimiters normal space and horizontal tab and then assigning everything after leading spaces/tabs to the loop variable. File names without file path can start with spaces. Therefore `"tokens=*"` is not best to process a list of file names. `"delims="` defines an empty list of delimiters which really disables line splitting. But file names without file path can start with `;`. So safe for file names is `"eol=| delims="` or `delims^=^ eol^=` to process really all files even those with a space or a `;` at beginning of file name.

Comment: For file names with full path it is safe to use `"tokens=*"` because of a full file path is either starting with a drive letter and a colon or with two backslashes on being a UNC path. It is of course a not really noticeable bit faster to disable line splitting behavior by using `"delims="` and define either vertical bar as end of line character which no file/folder name can contain or define even no character as end of line character. No delimiters and no eol character requires the strange looking syntax `delims^=^ eol^=` without double quotes around the two options.